# c++ operator delete overload not working for derived class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm trying to overload class specific operators new and delete to use custom allocator, for some abstract base class:

```
class Base abstract
{
public:
void * operator new (size_t sz)
{
   return tc_malloc(sz);
}
void operator delete(void* p){
   tc_free(p)
}
```

and I have a class "Derived" inherits from base (not directly, it's a complex inheritance chain, but eventually it's derived from base), and have:

```
a = new Derived();
.
.
delete a;
```

now a weird thing happens.. my operator new is called, calling tc_malloc, but for "delete a;" operator delete is called from delete_scalar.cpp (the default delete operator) this of course causes an exception as it tries to free memory not allocated by malloc.

any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? With GCC (latest) it is working fine.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? It will make answering easier.

Comment: Shouldn't the operators be declared static?

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli: Doesn't matter, there's a special rule in the C++ spec making these operators `static` class members even if the `static` keyword isn't used.

Comment: C++ has multiple inheritance.  Think about what you expect, and then how your expectation interacts with multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem:
it's because delete was called on an incomplete class.
more specifically, I had an .h file which looked something like this:

```
class A; //forward declaration
class User {
   A* a;
   User();
   ~User(){
      delete a; //this is the problem
}
```

so delete is called on an incomplete type, which has undefined behavior.
so neither the destructor nor the class specific delete operator is called here

Answer (score -1):

I think [C++ Virtual operator delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897394/c-virtual-operator-delete) could help understand what is going on here.

If I understand it correctly, always the delete operator of the most derived class is used, therefore it must use the one from Derived. And it seems, since you didn't declare one for Derived, the default operator is used.

Comment: not down voter, but if it's a duplicate, then flag it as such

Comment: Not sure if I'd call it a duplicate. It's related, certainly, but it's not the exact same question. Still figuring out what the threshold for something being a  duplicate is.

Comment: I tried overriding delete operator in the derived class as well, didn't work